# Can't create files on Galaxy SIII via USB

Tags: 4.3-jelly-bean, windows, mtp

I just got a Samsung Galaxy SIII and connected it to a Windows 7 PC. I installed the [Samsung Andorid (sic) USB drivers](http://developer.samsung.com/android/tools-sdks/Samsung-Andorid-USB-Driver-for-Windows) for Windows too.

When I connect the phone, I get the typical popup asking me whether I want to view the files. I do, and Windows Explorer lets me view the contents of the (emulated) SD card.

I can create folders there, but I can't create any files. What gives? How can I create files on the phone then?

---

Via `adb` I can see that there are no write permissions for other users:

```
ls -la
drwxrwxr-x root     sdcard_rw          2014-06-10 09:47 .downloadTemp
drwxrwxr-x root     sdcard_rw          2014-03-14 16:32 .face
drwxrwxr-x root     sdcard_rw          2014-06-05 15:53 .thumbnails
drwxrwxr-x root     sdcard_rw          2014-03-09 23:12 Alarms
drwxrwxr-x root     sdcard_rw          2014-03-09 23:12 Android
drwxrwxr-x root     sdcard_rw          2014-03-09 23:13 Application
drwxrwxr-x root     sdcard_rw          2014-03-14 16:30 DCIM
drwxrwxr-x root     sdcard_rw          2014-03-09 23:12 Documents
drwxrwxr-x root     sdcard_rw          2014-06-10 09:47 Download
drwxrwxr-x root     sdcard_rw          2014-03-09 23:12 Movies
drwxrwxr-x root     sdcard_rw          2014-03-09 23:12 Music
drwxrwxr-x root     sdcard_rw          2014-03-09 23:38 Nearby
drwxrwxr-x root     sdcard_rw          2014-03-09 23:12 Notifications
drwxrwxr-x root     sdcard_rw          2014-03-09 23:12 Pictures
drwxrwxr-x root     sdcard_rw          2014-03-09 23:33 Playlists
drwxrwxr-x root     sdcard_rw          2014-03-09 23:12 Podcasts
drwxrwxr-x root     sdcard_rw          2014-03-09 23:13 Ringtones
drwxrwxr-x root     sdcard_rw          2014-03-09 23:10 Samsung
```

I've also tried to restart Windows, install the [drivers from here](http://androidxda.com/download-samsung-usb-drivers), and still no dice.

Comment: Have you tried transferring via Kies?

Comment: We'd prefer not to have to install third party software to make a simple file transfer possible, especially of the Kies sort. Maybe if there was something more lightweight, but I'm wondering why that wouldn't be possible out of the box? I remember my old Android phones with an SD card allowed me to just write files on it.

Comment: Kies is Samsung's own software, so it isn't 3rd party (from the point of view of the phone, but I know what you mean). You SHOULD be able to copy as per normal, I see no reason that you couldn't, but Kies might be a work around or at least narrow the issue down.